# Assigning Object as Value and Reference doesnt work Properly in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am from Java Background. I have used objects as Call by Value and Reference in Java.
But When I am using these things in PHP i didnt achieve the my expected Result.

```
<?php
class A {

    public $t;

    function __construct() {

        $this->t = 100;
    }
}
/*By value */
echo 'By Value<br/>';
$obj1 = new A();
echo $obj1->t;
$obj2 = $obj1;
$obj2->t = 200;
echo $obj2->t;
echo $obj1->t; //expects Result 100 but it prints 200

/*By Reference */
echo '<br/>By Reference<br/>';
$obj3 = new A();
echo $obj3->t;
$obj4 = &$obj3;
echo $obj4->t;
$obj4->t = 500;
echo $obj4->t;
echo $obj3->t;
?>
```

When I am assigning one object to another one Object by value, If i modify the value of Property in Copied Object means, this will be affected Original Object too.

Plz Clear my doubt anyone...

Thanks...

Comment: as far as I know modern PHP only supports references to objects. you have to do a `clone` to get a reference to a new object.

Comment: Wouldn't Java behave exactly the same in your first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humm...PHP support both By Value and By Reference. However, there are a few quirks...

---

By default, PHP5 always assigns / passes objects by reference:

```
$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj2 = $obj1;

print spl_object_hash($obj1);
print "<br>";
print spl_object_hash($obj2);
```

Output:

```
000000001ef37c150000000046e30ead
000000001ef37c150000000046e30ead
```

Basically, both $obj1 and $obj2 are pointers to the same object.

---

However, this is not true for primitive types (such as integer, string, etc...)

```
$var1 = "some string";
$var2 = $var1;
$var1 = "foo";

print $var1;
print '<br>';
print $var2;
```

Output:

```
foo
some string
```

---

Using `&` you can pass by reference primitives too.

```
$var1 = "some string";
$var2 = &$var1;
$var1 = "foo";

print $var1;
print '<br>';
print $var2;
```

Output:

```
foo
foo
```

---

And you can pass objects by value too

```
$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj2 = clone $obj1;

print spl_object_hash($obj1);
print "<br>";
print spl_object_hash($obj2);
```

output:

```
0000000062516daa000000001745e928
0000000062516da9000000001745e928
```

---

**In Short, by default primitive types are passed by value while objects are passed by reference.**